# Двоеточие в "не было того оживления, которое... так и брызгало из ее глаз и улыбки: напротив, теперь огонь казался потушенным"

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Из "Анны Карениной":

> Раздевшись, она вошла в спальню, но на лице ее не только не было того оживления, которое в бытность ее в Москве так и брызгало из ее глаз и **улыбки: напротив**, теперь огонь казался потушенным в ней или где-то далеко припрятанным.

Почему автор поставил двоеточие перед "напротив"? Что оно тут выражает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная роль двоеточия, конечно, пояснение и разъяснение, но в 18 и 19 веках двоеточие употреблялось **чаще, его функции были размытыми.** Ср.: *Впрочем, я не прошу вас разделять мое мнение: если моя выходка вам кажется смешна – пожалуйста, смейтесь: предупреждаю вас, что это меня не огорчит нимало (М. Лермонтов)*;

*Одно ясно и подробно понимаем: другия хотя ясно в уме представляем, однако подробно изобразить не можем (М.Ломоносов)* – **двоеточие при противопоставлении**;

*Испытание натуры трудно, слушатели: однако приятно, полезно, свято (М. Ломоносов)* – **двоеточие перед противительным союзом однако**.

У М. Ломоносова довольно часто двоеточие стоит перед союзом со значением причины (в придаточных предложениях причины). Постепенно знак стал ассоциироваться со значением причины, обоснования. Поэтому в бессоюзных сложных предложениях он как бы взял на себя причинное значение, стал знаком содержательно значимым. Разъяснительно-пояснительная функция этого знака стойко сохраняется, но двоеточие начинает утрачивать некоторые позиции и уступать место другому знаку – тире.

Вот и у Толстого двоеточие **перед противопоставлением**. Он придерживался взгляда Ломоносова на пунктуацию - знаки препинания должны передавать логику построения фразы, это позже они будут совмещать логику и интонацию. В 19 веке двоеточие должно было предупреждать читателя  о чём-то важном, вот оно и предупреждает, что там будет противоположное мнение. Есть даже издания, где в этой фразе соединяются двоеточие и тире - предупреждение соединяется с противительной интонацией. Это уже в 20 веке строго разграничили их функции с учётом логики и интонации вместе. Кстати, сейчас тенденция к подмене одного знака другим, теперь уже говорят, что оба знака передают причинно - следственные отношения. Видимо, для авторов это облегчение, определённая свобода творчества.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение действительно выглядит несколько **архаичным**. Впрочем, чтобы придать ему современный вид, достаточно просто  добавить противительный союз А, тогда будет образован двойной союз **НЕ ТОЛЬКО…А НАПРОТИВ**. В этом случае на месте двоеточия будет стоять запятая:

*Раздевшись, она вошла в спальню, но на лице ее не только не было того оживления, которое в бытность ее в Москве так и брызгало из ее глаз и улыбки, **а напротив,** теперь огонь казался потушенным в ней или где-то далеко припрятанным.*

Но вернемся к авторскому варианту. Между частями сложного предложения **противительные** отношения, и по правилам в этом случае ставится **тире**.

Но это правило сюда не подходит, и  **двоеточие здесь – это единственно возможный вариант.**  Дело в том, что для обозначения противительных отношений используется **разделительное тире** с характерной интонацией (повышение голоса пред паузой). Кроме того, тире обычно ставится в **малораспространенных** предложениях, например: *Чин следовал ему – он службу вдруг оставил. Или: Огонь  не горел – казался потушенным или приглушенным.*  Наше предложение этим требованиям не отвечает.

А теперь о двоеточии. Основной функцией двоеточия является **пояснение**, при этом используется соответствующая **интонация**: неполное понижение голоса перед значительно увеличенной (предупредительной) паузой.

В заданном предложении **вторая часть поясняет первую,** раскрывая  **содержание противительных отношений** между ними. Такая функция двоеточия объясняется  значительной **распространенностью** простых предложений в составе сложного целого. И как уже говорилось, в современном синтаксисе в такой ситуации используется **двойной** союз, выражающий противопоставление.

**Примечание**. Считается, что тире во многих случаях может **заменить** двоеточие. Но это касается **присоединительного тире**, так как интонация в этом случае дублируется  (понижение тона перед паузой, только пауза не такая длительная).  Но в нашем случае **нет присоединения**, и требуется именно **пояснение** противительных отношений. Поэтому **тире не подходит**.

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие ставится ***при пояснении:*** не было оживления, а было (вот что). Вторая часть раскрывает смысл первой, дополняет её. В то же время при противопоставлении обычно ставят тире. Но, может быть, распространённость обеих частей говорит не в пользу последнего.